# UIImageView weird image property issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, uiimageview

I'm dealing with a super easy task that somehow introducing some difficulties...

All I'm trying to do is to create a view controller and set its UIImageView's image property to some image.
When I try to that, I get nil =\

```
GenericViewController *genericViewController = [[GenericViewController alloc] init];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Camera.png"];
genericViewController.genericImageView.image = image;
NSLog(@"%@", genericViewController.genericImageView.image);
```

Output: (null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine `genericImageView` is set up either in a nib or in the `-loadView` method. However, at the point in which you're trying to access the image view, the view for the VC hasn't been loaded yet. The quick fix is to call

```
(void)genericViewController.view;
```

before accessing `genericImageView`. This will force the view to load. The "better" approach would be to give `genericViewController` an image property that you assign to, then in its setter you can say

```
- (void)setGenericImage:(UIImage *)image {
    if (_genericImage != image) {
        [_genericImage release];
        _genericImage = [image retain];
        if ([self isViewLoaded]) {
            self.genericImageView.image = image;
        }
    }
}
```

and in `-viewDidLoad` you can say

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.genericImageView.image = self.genericImage;
}
```

This method, besides being more modular and architecturally-sound, also has the advantage where if the view controller's view is unloaded (say, another view is pushed onto the nav stack and a memory warning comes along), when it gets re-loaded it will still have the image.